# PHP log file color

Tags: php, linux, shell, logging

I'm writing a PHP log file class but I want to add color to the line that is written to the file.

The issue I'm having is the color changes the color of the terminal as well, what I want to achieve is to change color of line written to the log file only.

```
class logClass extends Singleton {

    private function checkDate() {
        return date("onSj");
    }

    public function logNotice($str) {
        $this->write($str, "\033[33m");
    }

    public function write($string, $color) {
        $fileName = $this->checkDate();
        $handle = fopen('error.log', 'a');
        fwrite($handle, "$color" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . $string . "\n");
       fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should add an end color mark sequence. Eg: `sprintf("\033[33m%s\033[0m", $text)`

Comment: @catalin.costache post it as an answer plz so I could mark it

Comment: Thats a nice idea to colorize logs! Thanks :) +1

Comment: logs should be colored:) il upload the class tomorrow on github ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should add an end color mark sequence. Eg: `sprintf("\033[33m%s\033[0m", $text)`

Here is a list of color codes taken from https://github.com/kevinlebrun/colors.php

```
$colorFormats = array(
        // styles
        // italic and blink may not work depending of your terminal
        'bold' => "\033[1m%s\033[0m",
        'dark' => "\033[2m%s\033[0m",
        'italic' => "\033[3m%s\033[0m",
        'underline' => "\033[4m%s\033[0m",
        'blink' => "\033[5m%s\033[0m",
        'reverse' => "\033[7m%s\033[0m",
        'concealed' => "\033[8m%s\033[0m",
        // foreground colors
        'black' => "\033[30m%s\033[0m",
        'red' => "\033[31m%s\033[0m",
        'green' => "\033[32m%s\033[0m",
        'yellow' => "\033[33m%s\033[0m",
        'blue' => "\033[34m%s\033[0m",
        'magenta' => "\033[35m%s\033[0m",
        'cyan' => "\033[36m%s\033[0m",
        'white' => "\033[37m%s\033[0m",
        // background colors
        'bg_black' => "\033[40m%s\033[0m",
        'bg_red' => "\033[41m%s\033[0m",
        'bg_green' => "\033[42m%s\033[0m",
        'bg_yellow' => "\033[43m%s\033[0m",
        'bg_blue' => "\033[44m%s\033[0m",
        'bg_magenta' => "\033[45m%s\033[0m",
        'bg_cyan' => "\033[46m%s\033[0m",
        'bg_white' => "\033[47m%s\033[0m",
    );
```

Example usage:

`sprintf($colorFormats['green'], $someText)`

Comment: hey @catalin.costache I had a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429683/changing-color-and-output-of-mamps-php-error-log-in-the-terminal).  Think you might be able to check it out?

Comment: Thank you. You can use this to avoid sending headers ```error_log(sprintf($colors[$color], $message));```.

Comment: Use `sprintf("\033[30;47m%s\033[0m", xxx)` to mix black foreground and white background