# Changing color and output of MAMP's php error log in the terminal

Tags: php, shell, logging, error-log

So the first priority here is trying to change the color of the out from the php error logs in my terminal.  I read in this article [PHP log file color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101302/php-log-file-color) 
about how they were using a class to do this but I'm not quite sure where to start.  Maybe the `php.ini` file?  Also I'm using the command

`tail -f /Applications/MAMP PRO/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/Resources/php5.5.10.ini`

to output the error logs.  If this is too difficult of a task to accomplish I'll let it go.  I just think it'd be nice to see some kind of syntax highlighting on the output from the file.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Would anything here http://serverfault.com/questions/177599/colour-tail-of-apache-logs help you? Specifically multitail?

Comment: There are some good resources there, but kind of would like to have it with syntax highlighting.  :)